# how to list all the files(with extension and without extension) under a specific directory

Tags: android, file, fileutils, hidden-files

I am currently able to get all the files with specific file extension

```
private List<String> getListFiles(File parentDir) {

    ArrayList<String> inFiles = new ArrayList<String>();

    File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();

    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {

                inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file));
        }
        else {
            if (file.getName().endsWith(".jpg")||file.getName().endsWith(".jpeg")) {
                inFiles.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }


                Log.d("fullpath", "full path is" + file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
    }

    return inFiles;
 }
```

But there are some more files in the directory those does not having any extension. I wanted to list those files also .i have tried this method . But i can't list those files.

```
String fileName=FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getName());
inFiles.add(fileName);
```

How to achieve this ? please help me out.

Comment: listFIiles() not returns the all files of parent folder ??

Comment: @SahdevRajput74 yeah , that is the question about

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the file extensions in your code. If you modify your code like this you'll get the other files also.

```
private List<String> getListFiles(File parentDir) {

    ArrayList<String> inFiles = new ArrayList<String>();

    File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();

    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {

                inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file));
        }
        else {
               inFiles.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    return inFiles;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah , but how to identify those files having no extensions ?(like how i am listing JPEG files) I wanted to list them separately. Because i need to apply some actions on those files does not having any extensions.

Comment: Extensions comes after a dot `.` Is that very hard to identify?  You can check if the file name as a `.` in it like, `file.getname().contains(".")`

Comment: cleaver answer . and i solved my problem. thank you @salman wahed

Comment: cleaver answer . and i solved my problem. thank you @salman wahed

Comment: Great to hear! It would be nice if you accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method

```
private static void getListFiles(File mInputDir,ArrayList<File> mFilesExt,ArrayList<File> mFilesNoExt) {
    File[] files = mInputDir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            getListFiles(file,mFilesExt,mFilesNoExt);
        }
        else {
            if (file.getName().contains(".")) {
                mFilesExt.add(file);
            }else{
                mFilesNoExt.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and call this method with your input directory to scan and an array of files with/without extension

```
File mInputDir = new File("/sdcard/Pictures/your_dir");
ArrayList<File> mFilesExt = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<File> mFilesNoExt = new ArrayList<>();

getListFiles(mInputDir,mFilesExt,mFilesNoExt);
```

Comment: this is what i was exactly looking for. thank you @bhumik

Answer (score 0):

First store all Filepath in one arraylist then try this code:

```
 if (arrayList_filenames.size() != 0) {

       for(int count = 0;count<arrayList_filenames.size() !=0){
            String extension = arrayList_filenames.get(count).toString().substring(arrayList_filenames.get(count).toString().lastIndexOf("."));
            Log.d("displayingextension", "****    " + extension);
          }
        }
```